# Integral of $\int \sqrt{36t^2 + 144t^4} dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \sqrt{36t^2 + 144t^4} dt$$

I really have no idea how to do this, I tried many types of substitution but it didn't work. I think I can use trig but it won't help much, also my book gives the answer in a form that wouldn't use trig sub. How do I do this?

Comment: Hint: Does factoring anything come to mind? Try the number and variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Factor out a $t^{2}$ to rewrite the integrand as:

$$\sqrt{t^{2}(36+144t^{2})} = t\sqrt{36+144t^{2}}$$

Then use the appropriate substitution.

Comment: I did that and it didn't seem particularly useful.

Comment: @PaulthePirate, why not? What happens when you make the substitution $u = 144t^{2}+36$? Then $du = 288tdt$... can you take it from here?

Comment: Oh I messed it up, thanks I see what to do now.

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help!

Comment: It is helpful indeed.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use the change variable $u=t^2$ and
$$\int\sqrt{4u+1}\; du=\frac{1}{6}(4u+1)^{3/2}+C$$